# on_member_update don't detect when running game or any other activity

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot detect if someone is playing game choosen by me (for example Minecraft), but it only detect changing role etc. except game activity. And even if it detect any update, it print as "None"

```py
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print(before.activity)
    print(after.activity)
```

Comment: Are your intents enabled? Also member update is only called in guilds.

Comment: It's enabled in discord bot settings. And what this second mean?

Comment: There’s probably presence update event. I cant get to the docs right now, I will see if I can find it later.

Comment: Here it is. [`on_presence_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member#discord.on_presence_update).

Comment: IT'S WORKING! Thank you a lot, i used questions from 2020. And it says it's new. You help me a lot and i'd probably fight with this for a loong time <3